# Robot Framework IDE Automate WPF

Tags: wpf, robotframework

I'm trying to automate an application I developed in C# (WPF) using Robot Framework.

I already explored a bunch of alternatives:

```
White Library
```

- https://github.com/Omenia/robotframework-whitelibrary
- https://github.com/TestStack/White

Doesn't seem to be working.

```
AutoItLibrary:
```

- https://pypi.org/project/robotframework-autoitlibrary/
- https://github.com/HW71/AutoItLibrary
- https://github.com/qitaos/robotframework-autoitlibrary

Doesn't work for WPF C# applications - Doesn't detect components

```
Sikuli
```

- https://github.com/rainmanwy/robotframework-SikuliLibrary
- http://rainmanwy.github.io/robotframework-SikuliLibrary/

Image detection doesn't work very well in WPF C# applications.

Has anyone been able to automate WPF C# applications using Robot Framework IDE?

Regards

Answer (score 1):

We just released first stable version of WhiteLibrary. It should do the job.
https://github.com/Omenia/robotframework-whitelibrary

```
pip install --upgrade robotframework-whitelibrary
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, [WhiteLibrary](https://github.com/Omenia/robotframework-whitelibrary) is build on the [White automation framework](https://github.com/TestStack/White) which has been deprecated since December 11, 2019. While [WhiteLibrary](https://github.com/Omenia/robotframework-whitelibrary) itself is not officially deprecated, the last release is also from 2019.

There appears to be a newer framework called [FlaUI](https://github.com/FlaUI/FlaUI), which is wrapped by [RobotFramework-FlaUI](https://github.com/GDATASoftwareAG/robotframework-flaui). This project is still under active development currently and likely a more future-proof choice than [WhiteLibrary](https://github.com/Omenia/robotframework-whitelibrary).